# Error Occurred "Type Mismatch" whenever my macro Loop through Column A and return more than 15 match string

Tags: excel, vba

Currently, I am facing an issue whenever my macro loops through Column A to search the string "Country Code:" and it returns the matched string more than 15 times. An error "Type Mismatch" is occurring. I have searched online but I could not find the solution.

I have checked and compared my string with the raw data and it is shown that there is no spelling error whatsoever. I have noticed if I insert a small amount of data where the macro returns around 7 results there is no issue.

This is my code. I apologize for my code as I am still learning and I found this sample online

```
Sub testCountryCode()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim toWs As Worksheet
Dim vDB, vR()
Dim i As Long, n As Long, c As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Set ws = Sheets("Database")
Set toWs = Sheets("CMF")

vDB = ws.UsedRange
c = UBound(vDB, 2)
For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
    If InStr(vDB(i, 1), "Country Code:") Then
        n = n + 1
        ReDim Preserve vR(1 To c, 1 To n)
        For j = 1 To c
            vR(j, n) = vDB(i, j)
        Next j
    End If
Next i
toWs.Range("a2").Resize(n, c) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
Sheets("Result").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: At what row does the error occur?

Comment: Hi FaneDuru , i have checked my Column A row for the error "Type Mismatch". It occur whenever i tried to CTRL+A data from pdf and paste into Column A. The row seems to be random